# Median-of-medians/quickselect filter in C

Tags: c, programming-challenge

[I wrote a quick-select filter in C on Wednesday.](https://github.com/WebClub-NITK/Hacktoberfest-2k19/pull/148#event-2684596020) (The code is below.)

It is a filter in the UNIX tradition:

- It reads from standard input `k`, the rank of the integer to select, `n`, the number of elements, and then `n` integers.
- It outputs the `k`th highest integer.

<sub>(A perhaps better design would take `k` as an argument—but a bigger gripe of mine is having to give `n`! Bonus points if an answer can show me how to avoid reading `n` from stdin or as an argument. I would read until EOF, but then I would have to deal with a growing array, I think.)</sub>

For the unfamiliar, [quickselect](https://brilliant.org/wiki/median-finding-algorithm/) can find the `k`th highest integer in `O(n)` time. The naïve selection algorithm sorts in place and then accesses element `k`, for `O(n lg n)` runtime. Quickselect does not sort large lists and achieves linear performance.

#### kth_largest.c

```
/*d. ben knoble 2019.10.02*/

/*
 * PROGRAM
 *
 * k_largest
 *
 * Finds the kth largest element of an array in O(n) time.
 *
 * Reads from standard input
 *
 * - k: which element to find
 * - n: number of elements
 * - n elements
 *
 * Outputs kth largest element to standard out.
 *
 * IMPLEMENTATION
 *
 * see kth_largest function
 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_longs(const void *a, const void *b) {
    long x = *(long *)a;
    long y = *(long *)b;
    if (x < y)
        return -1;
    else if (x > y)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void sort(long *a, size_t n) {
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(long), compare_longs);
}

size_t med_index(size_t i) {
    return (size_t)(floor(i/2));
}

void swap(long *a, long *b) {
    long t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

size_t partition(long pivot, long *array, size_t n_elts) {
    // find the pivot
    size_t pos = -1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_elts; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == pivot) {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    assert(pos >= 0);
    swap(&array[pos], &array[n_elts-1]);
    // now pivot is at the end of the array

    size_t i = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n_elts; ++j) {
        if (array[j] < pivot) {
            swap(&array[j], &array[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    swap(&array[i], &array[n_elts-1]);

    return i;
}

long kth_largest(size_t k, long *array, size_t n_elts) {
    size_t n_sublists = n_elts/5;
    long *medians = malloc(n_sublists * sizeof(long));
    if (medians == NULL) { err(1, NULL); }

    // sort sublists of 5 elements
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_sublists; ++i) {
        size_t start = i*5;
        size_t left = n_elts - start < 5 ? n_elts - start : 5;
        sort(&array[start], left);
        if (left == 5)
            medians[i] = array[start + 3];
        else
            medians[i] = array[start + med_index(left)];
    }

    // determine pivot (possibly recursively)
    long pivot;
    if (n_sublists < 5)
        pivot = medians[med_index(n_sublists)];
    else
        pivot = kth_largest(med_index(n_sublists), medians, n_sublists);

    // partition
    size_t rank = partition(pivot, array, n_elts);
    if (k < rank)
        return kth_largest(k, array, rank-1);
    else if (k > rank)
        return kth_largest(rank - k, &array[rank+1], n_elts-(rank+1));
    // else k == rank
    return pivot;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t k;
    size_t n_elts;
    scanf("%zd", &k);
    scanf("%zd", &n_elts);
    long *array = malloc(n_elts * sizeof(long));
    if (array == NULL) { err(1, NULL); }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_elts; ++i)
        scanf("%ld", &array[i]);

    printf("%ld\n", kth_largest(k, array, n_elts));
}
```

Comment: Aside: I've just realized I didn't actually free any of the memory I used 

Answer (score 3):

**Major stuff**

**Consider `const`**

Design: `kth_largest()` has a side effect of re-arranging `array`. this is surprising and not part of "Finds the kth largest element of an array in O(n) time."  I'd expect code to do the job without the side effect

```
// long kth_largest(size_t k, long *array, size_t n_elts) {
long kth_largest(size_t k, const long *array, size_t n_elts) {
```

**Small size error**

Code may call `err(1, NULL);` when `n_elts < 5` as `malloc(0)` can return `NULL`.  I'd expect code to work for sizes 1 to 4 also.

**Doubtful O() claim**

"Finds the kth largest element of an array in O(n) time."    Perhaps when `n` >>> `k`, but not in general.  I'd expect `O(n*k)`.  So perhaps

```
Finds the kth largest element of an array in O(n) time when k <<< n
otherwise O(n*k)
```

**No error check**

Do not trust user input follows the rules nor allocations always succeed.

```
long *array = malloc(n_elts * sizeof(long));
if (array == NULL) {
  Handle_Error();
}


for (size_t i = 0; i < n_elts; ++i) {
  // scanf("%ld", &array[i]);
  if (scanf("%ld", &array[i]) != 1) {
    Handle_Error();
  }
}
```

---

**Minor stuff**

**object vs type**

Rather than size to the type, size ot the object.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// qsort(a, n, sizeof(long), compare_longs);
qsort(a, n, sizeof *a, compare_longs);

// long *medians = malloc(n_sublists * sizeof(long));
long *medians = malloc(sizeof *medians * n_sublists);
```

**No need for floating point math**

`i/2` will already have "floor" the quotient before the `floor()`.  Absolutely no need for `floor()` and with its potential loss if precision for large `i`.

```
// return (size_t)(floor(i/2));
return i/2;
```

**`size_t` is an unsigned type**
**Enable all warnings**

`pos >= 0` is always true below.  A well enabled compilers would have warned.

```
size_t pos = -1;
...
assert(pos >= 0);
```

**Match specifier and type**

`"%zd"` does not match a `size_t`.  `"%zu"` does.  Also implies useful warnings were not enabled.  Save time - enable warnings.  See also [How to use “zd” specifier with `printf()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359)/

```
// scanf("%zd", &k);
// scanf("%zd", &n_elts);
scanf("%zu", &k);
scanf("%zu", &n_elts);
```

---

**Read until `EOF`**

"I would read until EOF, but then I would have to deal with a growing array, I think." --> Yes, good idea.  Confident this is up to D. Ben Knoble abilities, so will not post code.

Design idea: pass the `k` as an `argv[]` and the array via `stdin`.

Comment: Great feedback. Going to take this into consideration soon (I hope). One follow-up: my copy of the CLRS algorithm textbook gives a proof of this as being `O(n)` (section 9.3: Selection in worst-case linear time)